# Windows Authentication in FileSystemWatcher class

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

Basically I am trying to monitor folder path (new file created) using `FileSystemWatcher` class. When user drags and drops file in a folder, event is raised and I am able to get file name + file path.

I also want information who is copying the file (Windows user id).

Can somebody help with any direct or alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: copying info of the user to the folder OR from the folder?

Comment: Can you post any code you tried already?

Comment: There is a lot you cannot find out with FSW, it hooks into the file system at a very low level.  It only sees changes to the file system, it cannot know exactly which process made the change.  And therefore it cannot know what user account was used to run the process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way for you to get this information, because Windows does not keep track of who changed a file normally.

You can, however, use the security event log to monitor the changes to a folder. You'll need to [configure the auditing beforehand](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130418-00/?p=4623), and then you can use the `FullPath` from FileSystemEventArgs to query the security log.